A theoretical experiment about gravity and propulsion
An observer travels in a spherical ship drifting through space. The observer cannot 'see' anything outside the ship.
At some time, the ship approaches a massive object P and describes an hyperbolic orbit. A pendulus or other device let the observer measure the acceleration while it is perceptible. They can even measure some relation between the geometry of the orbit and the mass of P.
Later, very far away from P, a fuel that is homogeneously distributed around the ship is burnt to give the ship an acceleration pattern, identical to the former. But now, the mass of the ship is lesser than before. No noise or heat, etc could be detected from inside.
Is there any way that the observer can distinguish between those two events, now or afterwards? (always inside the ship, of course)
So, can the mass of a closed system be measured from inside itself?

If the observer is deflected by the gravity of a planet, he is in free fall. If a rocket motor propels him, he feels the thrust.
One way to think about this is that gravity accelerates everything in the ship the same. So the ship does not push the observer. Whereas the rocket motor pushes the ship, and the ship pushes the observer.
Another way to think about it is that the planet curves spacetime so that geodesics become curved. The ship and everything in it is not accelerated. The ship follows a hyperbolic geodesic.
There is a way the observer can detect the presence of a planet if the ship is big enough or he has sensitive enough apparatus. The side of the ship closest to the planet feels a stronger gravitational force than the far side. Two freely floating masses will be accelerated with respect to each other. This is called a tidal force.
From the general relativity view point, the two masses are accelerated with respect to each other becayse the geodesic closer to the planet is more strongly curved.

Ah, so the pendulus and the ship describe the same trajectory. So P remains undetected. Please ignore tidal forces.

Then, the mass of the ship doesn't exist at all for the observer, and even the mass of P!! Is it like for a dumb enough human observer, the Earth is flat?

The mass of the ship and P are the same if the ship is near a planet or not.

You can, in principle, measure the mass of a closed spaceship from inside the spaceship. If a mass is accelerated inside the ship (for example by a spring mounted inside the ship) a sufficiently sensitive accelerometer mounted on the spaceship will show the ship's acceleration from the reaction force to the force on the mass.
To expand on this:
Assume firstly that we can ignore tidal effects. Also assume for simplicity that the spaceship is not accelerating. Equip the ship with a chamber containing a known mass $m$ attached by light springs to opposite walls of the chamber, and with accelerometers in the ship and in the mass $m$ to measure accelerations parallel to the springs.
Start the mass $m$ oscillating. The two accelerometers will show the acceleration of the mass $m$ to be $a$ (non-zero), and the acceleration of the rest of the ship (mass $M$) to be $A$ at some particular time. These accelerations are relative to the centre of mass of the entire ship including the oscillating mass.
Newton's second and third laws of motion can be applied because the ship is not accelerating and the speed of $m$ relative to the ship will be small compared with the speed of light. Applying these laws and ignoring direction give $am=AM$. Since we know $m$ (known mass) and we have measured $a$ and $A$ we can calculate the mass $M$. This is the mass of the ship without the oscillating mass $m$; the mass of the entire ship will be $M+m$.

That reaction, would not be $0$ by Gauss' law?

Consider a 1 kg box with a 500 g weight on springs inside it. Its movement will not be even, and a small observer inside would definitely feel it.

If the box and the spring and the weight are all falling on the same geodesic, and you ignore tidal effects, then no, you can't tell if you're falling near a massive object or not.

@MissUnderstands True. But you can measure the mass of the box from inside the box. This is a partial answer to the last part of the question.

@Peter "you can measure the mass of the box from inside the box"  == In free fall, without using the tidal force, in a spherical box? How?

@MissUnderstands, see my expanded answer.

Wrong again, Albert. Inside a hollow sphere, the gravitational pull from the surrounding shell is everywhere zero. You're weightless inside a metal sphere at the center of the Earth, no matter how dense or thick the walls are.  You wouldn't be able to detect the fact that you were inside a planet instead of floating in space.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

When you say:
At some time, the ship approaches a massive object P and describes an hyperbolic orbit. A pendulus or other device let the observer measure the acceleration while it is perceptible.
There is no proper acceleration in this scenario.  Without looking outside, the astronaut has no way of knowing the planet is there unless he can measure tidal forces. Even if he is falling into a black hole or is even inside the black hole, there is no indication of this in his local environment. The way he eventually discovers his fate is when tidal forces become strong enough to notice and then rip the matter apart.

Gravity would only be zero at the exact center of the interior of the ship.
The only things needed to determine if the ship is in a gravitational field, or is accelerating, is a free object and a clock. Place the object just off center and calculate the time required for it to reach the wall. Do this from multiple sides of just off center. It will take less time in the direction of an exterior mass,or in the opposite direction of acceleration.
